# Highlight text only, with opacity to the background

Tags: css

I have some text in my header which can be hard to see on different viewports. So, I want to highlight it as if you select it on a website (but black with opacity instead of the default blue).

I currently styled my header text like this:

```
header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 700;
```

(site: topsok [dot] nl).

I tried some different things with `<mark>` and `background:` in my stylesheet, but I wasn't able to add opacity to the selection. I would like it to look exactly the same way it looks now when you manually select the text on the header.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
h1 {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    display: initial;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that comes very close to perfect. Only thing is that the spacing between lines is less than normal. 
So now the selection works, but the selection of line 1 lies on top of the selection of line 2 - which results in dark black lines between the text. Excuse my baad english, I dont know how I can explain this better. I have updated the website, so you can see for yourself. Thanks!

Comment: You need to increase your `line-height` to 88px (for me at least).

Comment: yeah, came across that solution but I dont really want to change that

Comment: I believe that it is a font related issue then as it is to do with the character heights. You could try another font? Otherwise I'm not aware of any other things you could try